# JAVA POI XML and XLSX

Tags: apache-poi

I've used JAVA POI to generate XML and import to excel 2010 format .xlsx file.
However, when I open .xlsx file, it is corrupted and below error pops up. Please kindly help.

Replaced Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part with XML error. Illegal name character. Line 575, column 1916.

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: Can you post the xml somewhere?  I suspect there's a bad character in the xml (e.g. a tag that starts with a digit)

Comment: unless you provide more information here it is not possible to help you